# destroy empty changesets

Tags: tfs

I just deleted several TeamProjects in my TeamProjectCollection in TFS.

Now there are many empty changesets: All files that were changed using the changeset do not exist anymore. While destroying the changesets, TFS did even change the changeset's comment to

`All of the changes in this changeset have been destroyed.`

Is there any way to actually delete/destroy these empty changesets as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

You can only roll them back but that won't help you since the changes are already destroyed.